# How to Retrieve data of Gallery Shortcode and display it above a post

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I'm trying to style my theme without resorting to custom fields. For gallery posts type, most premium themes are using custom field which is the method I used till now. With it, I could then retrieve the attachment ID's and display the images in a slideshow above the post title & content.

However this results in theme lock, and I was wondering if there is any way to do the below:

1. Retrieve the first gallery shortcode used in a post to output the images as slideshow above the Post title and
2. also remove the shortcode from within the post so it is not displayed again in the content.

I understand it would involve lot of code so if anyone could just point me in the right direction would be appreciated. I know bit of PHP and can tweak code but not great with creating something from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeking the same solution. I am going to create a gallery filter function - an extension to this. Do you want to collaborate?

```
function get_post_gallery( $post = 0, $html = true ) {
$galleries = get_post_galleries( $post, $html );
$gallery = reset( $galleries );

/**
 * Filter the first-found post gallery.
 *
 * @since 3.6.0
 *
 * @param array       $gallery   The first-found post gallery.
 * @param int|WP_Post $post      Post ID or object.
 * @param array       $galleries Associative array of all found post galleries.
 */
return apply_filters( 'get_post_gallery', $gallery, $post, $galleries );
}
```

Comment: Would love to collaborate but I'm not that good with programming. I'm more of a theme designer.